# How can I check if a YouTube video allows embedded play

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

YouTube channels can disallow their videos to be played in an embedded YouTube player. I'm working with user generated content, where the user chooses a video of their choice to be embedded (with the YouTube iFrame API), and I need to explain to the user why their video cant be embedded, so I need to detect this specific reason for failure, rather than simply detecting that the video wont play. I want to check this before actually feeding the video to the player.

---

I'm wondering if I can get the info as a response to a v3 data query like the one I'm currently doing:

```
$.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=***&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics&id=' + videoID, function(data, status, xhr) { ...
```

I saw [something like this talked about involving the v2 data API, here.](https://www.quora.com/With-JavaScript-is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-YouTube-video-is-set-to-allow-embedding)

Is there a way to check whether the video is restricted from being played as an embed beforehand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be getting an [onError 101 event.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events)

You can also filter videos using [`videoEmbeddable`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters) in a search.

Comment: Perfect. I didnt notice the 101 error event in the docs, thanks

Comment: Hey from what [Im reading about the v2 API](https://www.quora.com/With-JavaScript-is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-YouTube-video-is-set-to-allow-embedding) you could check if the video was embedded without actually trying to play it (I want to check before playing it, not after feeding it  to the player), and Im wondering if this can been done with the v3 API. For example I have a query string like this: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=***&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics&id=' + videoID` - could I somehow get that info included with results to a query like this?

Comment: [`video`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) has a property `status.embeddable`.

Comment: perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.